# Sql Server CTE "multi- part identifier could not be bound."

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

My last question on this same cte query was answered so quickly, I thought I'd bounce this next one off you sql gurus. If I could go over my basic logic, then show my code and syntax error, any help would be greatly appreciated..

I have three tables for a stock trading system: a symbols table: as the name suggests it's a list of ticker symbols, a daily pricing/ volume table: again, as- described, and each record has a date field and symbol field as well as the pricing info, and lastly a trading dates table: the reference for all trading dates in our query.

I'd like to return a recordset with two fields: a symbol and a date. The pair represents all trading dates and symbols that don't have corresponding pricing/ vol data for that symbol in the pricing volume table. Make sense? On my query, I'm getting the error message: "The multi-part identifier "Symb.Symbol" could not be bound." Here's my cte query:

```
WITH Symb AS
(
     SELECT Symbol
     FROM tblSymbolsMain
),

DatesNotNeeded AS
(
     SELECT Date
     FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol
     WHERE (tblDailyPricingAndVol.Symbol = Symb.Symbol)
),

WideDateRange AS
(
     SELECT TradingDate
     FROM tblTradingDays
     WHERE (TradingDate >= dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()) AND (TradingDate <= dbo.LatestAvailableDataDownloadDateTime())
),

DatesNeeded AS
(
     SELECT TradingDate
     FROM WideDateRange wdr
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DatesNotNeeded)
)

SELECT Symb.Symbol, DatesNeeded.TradingDate
FROM Symb CROSS JOIN DatesNeeded
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This:

```
DatesNotNeeded AS
(
     SELECT Date
     FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol
     WHERE (tblDailyPricingAndVol.Symbol = Symb.Symbol)
),
```

Needs to be this:

```
DatesNotNeeded AS
(
     SELECT Date
     FROM tblDailyPricingAndVol inner join Symb on
         tblDailyPricingAndVol.Symbol = Symb.Symbol
),
```

But your query still won't work, since this:

```
DatesNeeded AS
(
     SELECT TradingDate
     FROM WideDateRange wdr
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DatesNotNeeded)
)
```

Needs to be this:

```
DatesNeeded AS
(
     SELECT TradingDate
     FROM WideDateRange wdr
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DatesNotNeeded d where d.Date = wdr.TradingDate)
)
```

But really, you can do this without CTEs, like this:

```
select
    sm.Symbol,
    tb.TradingDate
from
    tblSymbolsMain sm
    cross join tblTradingDays tb
    left join tblDailyPricingAndVol dp on
        sm.Symbol = dp.Symbol 
        and tb.TradingDate = dp.Date
where
    tb.TradingDate between 
        dbo.LatestAvailableDataDownloadDateTime()
        and dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDatetime()
    and dp.Date is null
```

This query grabs all the symbols from `tblSymbolsMain` and all the dates between your last and next available dates from `tblTradingDays`. Then it does a `left join` on `tblDailyPricingAndVol` and filters out any row that found a match.

You could also use `not exists` in lieu of a `left join`, which I think is a bit clearer, too:

```
select
    sm.Symbol,
    tb.TradingDate
from
    tblSymbolsMain sm
    cross join tblTradingDays tb
where
    tb.TradingDate between 
        dbo.LatestAvailableDataDownloadDateTime() 
        and dbo.NextAvailableDataDownloadDatetime()
    and not exists (
        select
            1
        from
            tblDailyPricingAndVol dp
        where
            dp.Symbol = sm.Symbol
            and dp.Date = tb.TradingDate
    )
```