# Multipart identifier could not be bound error in 'multi-level' CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression

I am trying to get a specific set of rows based on row numbers from my table. To that I am trying to use the following sql query with common table expression (cte). I have marked the part in the query that is giving me issues.

The issue I am having is different because the second query in the CTE has a where clause based on a parameter so, I cannot join the table as shown here: [Sql Server CTE "multi- part identifier could not be bound."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8720091/sql-server-cte-multi-part-identifier-could-not-be-bound)

I am sure I am missing some fundamentals of CTE syntax because the setup itself makes sense to me and I can make it work if I were to get rid of the CTE. Could someone please tell me what I am missing?

```
;with cte as (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Created) RNUM, * 
        FROM Notes 
        WHERE BookId = @BookId AND Username = @Username
    ), 
    offsetrow as (
        SELECT RNUM
        FROM cte
        WHERE cte.NoteId = @StartOffset
    )

    SELECT * 
    FROM cte
    WHERE cte.RNUM > offsetrow.RNUM --The multi-part identifier 'offset.RNUM' could not be bound.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to put offsetrow in from clause in last select statement my friend. Please do something like this :

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM cte,offsetrow
 WHERE cte.RNUM > offsetrow.RNUM
```

Comment: Thanks! Ugh. Can't believe this just happened.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the problem here is that you are selecting from only one resultset (`cte`). Your expression code currently produces two : `cte` and `offsetrow`.

You should join the two together (as you would with two classic tables / views).

Comment: Thank you for replying. `cte` and `offsetrow` are serving two different purpose in the final select statement. Can I not use the two tables separately?

Comment: I see what you mean now. Ugh! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue, and found that if I wanted to select certain columns from CTE1 and then Join to CTE2, Hiren's solution doesn't work. Instead I had to do the following

`SELECT ....
FROM CTE1
LEFT JOIN CTE2
ON CTE1.Column= CTE2.Column`

This worked for me